# How to compile SCSS with scssphp

Tags: php, sass

I'm currently trying to compile some SCSS which I'm receiving via a form request. The current workflow is that the user submits form data as follows:

`{"$background_color":"#f3f3f3","$logo_url":"https:\/\/logo.co\/random"}`

I then transform this input to the following:

`$background_color: '#f3f3f3';
$logo_url: 'https://logo.co/random'`

This should be valid for the purposes of compiling it to CSS so I run it through SCSSPHP with the following:

`$scss->addImportPath(Storage::disk('tmp'));
 $output = $scss->compile("@import 'test'; $statement ");`

No errors are triggered when I run this and the output is:

`@import 'test';`

My `test.scss` is as follows:

```
$background_colour: 'red'
$logo_url: 'https://test.com'

.logo {
  background-image: $logo_url;
}

.background_colour {
    background-colour: $background_colour;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And what would be your problem? I don't understand, sorry. Maybe CSS syntax? `background-image: url($logo_url);` &  `background-color: $background_colour;`?

Comment: Hey, so my custom variables which I'm passing in aren't getting set. I should receive the CSS as an output but instead I only receive `@import 'test'` as an output. Edited the CSS as you laid it out but I still have the same issue :/

Comment: add also `;` after your 2 variables

Comment: Added and still no luck...

Comment: From experimenting with it, it seems like scssphp is struggling to read the variable. It doesn't give an error but simply doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're **not passing a string** to this function.
Parse your scss as a string by using the function **file_get_contents**

```
require_once "scssphp/scss.inc.php";

use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;

$scss = new Compiler();

// Gets the content of the scss file in string format

$scss_string = file_get_contents(path/to/scss.file);

echo $scss->compile($scss_string);
```

Comment: Yup, I have the compiler included etc. My understanding was that the import path is the folder containing the SCSS file and then you do `@import "test"` as you would in a regular SCSS file. My full code looks like: ```$scss = new Compiler();
            //Get theme SCSS file from request
            $scss->addImportPath(Storage::disk('tmp'));
            $output = $scss->compile('@import "test"; ' . $statement);
            return $output;```

Comment: I understand, but like you also said in a comment. He has trouble with the variable so file_get_contents(path/to/scss.file); will give you a string for sure :)

Comment: That worked! Super strange that it couldn't grab the variable as a string. I wonder if there is a neater workaround? I'm still not able to parse the user input as that is also stored as a variable.

Comment: For the user input: var_dump the variable, see if it's a string, if not parse/convert it as a string. Can you also mark my answer as the correct one/ solved?  Thanks!

Comment: Yup I was casting it to a string but it's still not overwriting the variables in my `test.scss` file weirdly :/

Comment: Hmm, what are you trying exactly? (It sounds you want to do something client side that happens on the server side.)

Comment: So essentially I have a CSS file that is running and a manifest.json file of SCSS variables that can be customised, along with the SCSS files that make up the final CSS. The front-end then generates a form based on those variables and a user can customise them. Then the request is sent to the backend and I override the old defaults with the user-selected variables and create the new CSS file via scssphp.